# Getting URL from site after submitting form

Tags: java, android, selenium, networking, selendroid

**So the site that Im targeting works like this:**

The sites name is **https://masterbattlerite.com/**. https://masterbattlerite.com/ works like this:

1. Enter username in search bar of the site
2. Press the search button (or hit enter)
3. The site directs you to the userpage with the username you entered.
4. the URL is now something like **https://masterbattlerite.com/238338348**
5. that number (238338348) is the id of the user
6. I want to know how to get that **id** as a string in my app

I found out of Selendroid but you need some sort of server to be able to emulate a browser? My app will be released on the play store so I don't want my users needing to start their own selendroid server everytime to do this (maybe Im wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, can you use an HTTP library/framework and POST to the same location the site posts to and retrieve the id from the redirect the server sends? You may have to set some extra (possibly hidden on the webpage) parameters to get it to work.

EDIT: ok, it's even easier with the site you mentioned... if you search for a username of bob, you just GET this URL: http://masterbattlerite.com/profile/bob/lookup
and it returns some nice JSON with the id in it like so: {"status":"success","player":{"id":1268,"user_id":"5688","name":"bob","title":504,"avatar":30016}}

BTW - I figured all of this out using the Chrome developer's tools. Learn to use it - it is your friend.

Comment: Hi, I don't thinks that works in my case, since I cant see where the site is posting the form data too. I edited my post to the specific site so you can see yourself what I mean.

Comment: imma look this up if this works and if it does imma find your house and buy you a beer because I've been trying to find this out for 1 week and only thing I got is frustration

Comment: it works. I tried it a few times - I used bob, brian, and joe. all worked. Like I said, learn to use Chrome developer tools (or Firebug on Firefox). They are amazingly handy tools.